# Counting number of nodes in Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am struggling to understand why the function `CountNodes()` below counts all the nodes in a BST.

If we assume we have the following BST:

```
            20
          /   \
         10    30
        /  \  /  \
       5  15 25  35
```

If I call `CountNodes(pointer to root node 20);` then wouldn't the relevant `if` statement:

```
    if(root->left!=NULL)
    {
        n=n+1;
        n=CountNodes(root->left);
    }
```

simply look at node `10` and say, yes it is not null, add 1 to the counter `n`, and then call `CountNodes(pointer to 10)` which would then just send us down the left branch again to `5`. Then when at `5` the `left` and `right` variables are `NULL` and hence the whole `CountNodes` function just returns `n` equal to `int 3`.

I guess I am struggling to understand exactly when the value of the argument to `CountNodes` is updated. Do we look `right` and check if its `NULL` and update the counter before we update the argument value in the first recursive call to `CountNodes(pointer to 10)` in the left look even though the right look appears after the left recursive call in the code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int n=1;

struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

struct node* getNode(int data)
{
    node* newNode=new node();
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->left=NULL;
    newNode->right=NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct node* Insert(struct node* root, int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        return getNode(data);

    if (data < root->data)
        root->left  = Insert(root->left, data);

    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = Insert(root->right, data);

    return root;
}


int CountNodes(node*root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;

    if(root->left!=NULL)
    {
        n=n+1;
        n=CountNodes(root->left);
    }

    if(root->right!=NULL)
    {
        n=n+1;
        n=CountNodes(root->right);
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{  
    node* root=NULL;
    root=Insert(root,10);
    Insert(root,5);
    Insert(root,20);
    Insert(root,4);
    Insert(root,8);
    Insert(root,15);
    Insert(root,25);
    cout<<"Total No. of Nodes in the BST = "<<CountNodes(root)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the global variable `n`. It's quite wrong using global variables with side effects in the recursion...

Comment: I suggest you try to find a solution where `n` is a *local* variable instead of global.

Comment: At first, you *absolutely* should define n as a local variable of `countNodes`. Then by *assigning* n as result of recursive call, you lose previous information. You'd need `+=` instead...

Comment: Also by doing `n = ...` followed by `n = ...` you lose the first assignment.

Comment: Actually, you can do it really simple: `return root == nullptr ? 0 : 1 + count(root->left) + count(root->right);` – the null-check in next recursive call compensates the dropped check for children being available. `1 + ...` counts current node itself, which replaces the `n = n + 1` you have now.

Comment: `struct node*` is pretty much C. If you are writing c++, omit the `struct` keyword. (i.e. use `node*` instead)

Comment: Are you aware that `std::set` (or `std::map`) actually is a binary search tree as well? Typically implemented as red-black-tree, so you won't get degenerate trees either... (degenerate tree: what would your implementation produce on inserting *sorted* data???).

Comment: Off-topic: You should prefer C++ *keywords* (`nullptr`) over old (obsolete?) C *macros* (`NULL`).

Comment: You should replace `getNode` function with a constructor: `node(int data) : data(data), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { }` – then you'd create new nodes by simply `return new node(data);`

Answer (score 4):

You are overwritting the value of n

```
    n=CountNodes(root->left);
```

You should be adding the count from the sub tree.

```
    n = n + CountNodes(root->left);
```

There is also another bug in that you are counting this node twice if the node has a left and right tree and never counting it if the node has no subtrees.

```
if(root->left!=NULL)
{
    n=n+1;                      // Adding one for this node.
    n=CountNodes(root->left);
}

if(root->right!=NULL)
{
    n=n+1;                      // Adding one for this node again?
    n=CountNodes(root->right);
}
```

I think you should be doing:

```
if(root->left!=NULL)
{
    n = n + CountNodes(root->left);
}

if(root->right!=NULL)
{
    n = n + CountNodes(root->right);
}
n = n + 1;
```

The next thing is that you check for null on entry into the function. So you don't need to test for null before doing a recursive call.

```
n = n + CountNodes(root->left);
n = n + CountNodes(root->right);
n = n + 1;
```

We can then simplify this to:

```
int CountNodes(node* root)
{
    if (root == nullptr) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + CountNodes(root->left) + CountNodes(root->right);
}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need those two if's, if you drop them, the null-check for root in recursive call will catch up and thus resulting in n += 0...